# Check if files in PATH is exists in cmd

Tags: windows

I know command to show all paths in PATH

```
echo %path:;=&echo.%
```

But how with command `exist` chech if is exists

Comment: Parse the string returned into an array, then loop through the array, until you determine the string your looking for exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one-line command that will do this, but I have incorporated the requirements into the following batch code:-

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set P=%PATH%
:Loop
for /f "delims=; tokens=1*" %%f in ("!P!") do (
    if exist "%%f"\*.* ( echo "%%f": valid ) else ( echo "%%f": not a directory )
    set P=%%g
    if not "%%g" == "" goto Loop
)
```

I looked for ways to avoid the `goto`, but in the end it was simpler to use it.

The `for` command splits `%P%` into `%%f` and `%%g` at the first `;`.

Note the requirement for delayed expansion, so that `P` will be expanded with its current value on each pass of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply like say @Ramhound parse string and use for

```
for %%i in (%path:;=,%) do (exist %%i)
```

Comment: This won't work if there are embedded blanks or certain other characters (eg `(`, `)`) in any of the paths. Plus, what is the `exist` command? The only standard use of `exist` in `cmd` is a clause in the `if` command, eg `if exist "%%f"\*.* (echo %%f is a directory) else echo %%f is not a directory`, which will show an error if the path does not exist, or if it is a file, rather than a directory.